# React Hoooks: change children state from parent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, parent-child

I have a problem to change state for a child from the parent component. 
Here is a sample sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/parent-child-communication-hooks-34tjn?file=/src/components/Child.jsx

Here is my goal: When a user clicks "Turn on all button" in the Parent component, All of the children components will be turned on together. Turn off will turn off all children.

But Still, It is necessary to control each child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. I see in your CodeSandbox that you started using React Hooks. Other than the `useState` hook we have the `useEffect` which will be triggered after the dependency has changed. You can achieve that by using this hook.

Simply add a new prop to your Child Component, this prop will contain the state value for the parent, we will call this `parentValue`. This is your Parent Component

```
//Parent.jsx
//your code
      {childrentdata.map(x => (
        <ChildComponent
          name={x.name}
          buttonOn={state.ParentOn}
          parentValue={state.ParentOn}
        />
      ))}
```

Then, in your Child Component add the hook

```
useEffect(() => {
    setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, buttonOn: props.parentValue }));
  }, [props.parentValue]);
```

The hook will watch for props and state changes that we specify in the array dependency as the second argument. So, everytime the parent toggle changes, it will change all the children. There is a change I made, if you notice I'm using a callback inside your `setState`, this is the way we can get the actual value for the state without getting a stale value. So, is a good practice to use this callback to prevent side effects.

Comment: "module react has no exported member setState". Also, cannot find name "props." Where are some of these variables coming from?

Comment: Hi @CalebJay please check the code sandbox from the question. setState refers to the dispatch function created when using the useState hook and props... well, the props passed to the component.